# jQuery Mobile, vertical navigation strip like the alphabetical list on iphone contacts

Tags: javascript, list, jquery-mobile, navigation, vertical-scrolling

Can any one recommend a resource for creating a vertical navigation strip using jQuery Mobile for rapid scrolling like the alphabetical navigation strip on the iphone "phone" app contacts page?

Answer (score 0):

maybe tale a look at https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview . Doesn't look too complicated